# How to set parameter in Visual page object from apex

Tags: apex, developer-console, standard, visualforce

I am facing a problem when try to put parameter on apex page standard controller
I created Apex standard controller and passed it to page controller

the code I kept below. Is it possible to put param like this

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc   = new ApexPages.StandardController(pj);
ManageCtrPage obj = new ManageCtrPage (sc);

sc.getParameters().put('Type','SAVEEXIT'); //// Getting error if i try to add this
```

In normal way the ManageCtrPage.apex will get 'Type' param from ManageCtrPage.vfp page but i need to create it in developer console for testing purpose.I have to use only  apex code and simulate vfp params.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is a property in the controller, you can access it like a normal variable:

```
obj.Type = 'SAVEEXIT';
```

If you're reading the value from the URL query string, you use `ApexPages.currentPage()`.

From there, you can set the parameters by manipulating the `Map<String, String>` returned from `getParameters()`. Here's a typical example:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Type','SAVEEXIT');
```